# get a jpeg using file_get_content from form a URL with no jpeg in it syntax.

Tags: php

I am trying to use file_get_content to get a jpeg from an remote URL and then copy it on my server.

the url is : http://mediaserver.centris.ca/media.ashx?id=ADD242BD121361ADDBF9EDBDBB&t=pi&sm=c&w=640&h=480

if pasted in a browser it will produces a jpeg  (save as will show it named media.jpeg) ...

the follwing PHP :

```
$contents=file_get_contents('http://mediaserver.centris.ca/media.ashx?id=ADD242BD121361ADDBF9EDBDBB&t=pi&sm=c&w=640&h=480');
```

will yield

> Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in
>   /home/user/public_html/dir/centris.php on line 208
>
> Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(http://mediaserver.centris.ca/media.ashx?id=ADD242BD121361ADDBF9EDBDBB&t=pi&sm=c&w=640&h=480):
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known in /home/user/public_html/dir/centris.php on
>   line 208

any thoughts on how to import this image ?  (I tried COPY with the same results)

Comment: the first error says it all - your server is not able to resolve mediaserver.centris.ca to an IP address. Its DNS resolver is not configured properly.

Comment: UPDATE ... i used CURL and it worked ... not sure what was happenning

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the string before passing it into [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents). Here is an example using your code as a starting point.

```
$raw_url = 'http://mediaserver.centris.ca/media.ashx?id=ADD242BD121361ADDBF9EDBDBB&t=pi&sm=c&w=640&h=480';
$url = urlencode($raw_url);
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

As the manual for `file_get_contents` states:

> If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you
> need to encode the URI with urlencode().

**EDIT** Could also be DNS issues on the machine running the PHP code.  What happens when you run this from the command line?

```
curl -I "http://mediaserver.centris.ca/media.ashx?id=ADD242BD121361ADDBF9EDBDBB&t=pi&sm=c&w=640&h=480"
```

I get the following `200 OK` headers back from the server when I run it. The command `curl -I` will show you the headers returned from a request.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Content-Length: 51837
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Expires: Fri, 27 Dec 2013 21:41:08 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 27 Nov 2013 21:41:08 GMT
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer ... that just gives me Warning:  file_get_contents(http%3A%2F%2Fmediaserver.centris.ca%2Fmedia.ashx%3Fid%3DADD242BD121361ADDBF9EDBDBB%26t%3Dpi%26sm%3Dc%26w%3D640%26h%3D480): failed to open stream: No such file or d...

Comment: i just tried the COPY function with  loop for all 24 pics ... randomly between 12 AND 18 will copy, with the remaining getting the Warning:  copy(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/user/public_html/immo/centris.php on line 230 ERROR  ?????

Comment: i get :  http not supported or disable in libcurl